# Android In-app billing - which documentation to follow?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I've just been working through [this](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html) Android developers guide, but have just found [this](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html) one also on the Android developer site, which appears to use different classes.

Which is the best one to use? (Neither have dates on, so it's not obvious which is newest.)

My app is for Android version 11+.

Comment: I have used the first one and its seems to be working fine.
FYI i have used for consumable purchase.

Answer (score 0):

Both documents are the same thing - there is no version/time difference.

The first one is an in-depth reference and guide. Skim the first one to understand the general concepts of IAB. Then start reading the second one which is actually a tutorial on how to implement IAB in your app. The second one includes some helper classes which makes your life way easier. If you only want to read the first article and implement all features by yourself you are wasting time!

Note that the second article is actually based on a App Sample that is included in your sdk. Read the app line by line along with the second article you mentioned. You will master it in a day!

Comment: I have this all working now by just following the first tutorial. Thanks for clarifying the difference though.

Comment: Congrats! But please know that the first tutorial does not show you any security implementation in your app. If you only use the code provided in the first tutorial, your in-app-purchases will be vulnerable to piracy. This might not matter if you are not developing a very big app.